# Append jQuery working but onclick is not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have filter for producttypes which is getting created as per enteries in database via ajax:

HTML Part:

```
<ul id="foodtype"></ul>
```

Ajax Code to show filter:

```
    function showtypes(){
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "ajax/incl/showtype",
          data:'',
          dataType : 'json',
          cache: false,
          success: function(records1){
                $('#foodtype').html(makefoodType(records1));
          }
        });
       }

       function makefoodType(data1){
          var tbl_body = "";
            $.each(data1, function() {
              var tbl_row = "",
                  currRecord = this;
              $.each(this, function(k1 , v1) {
            tbl_row += "<li><input type=checkbox id="+v1+" name="+v1+" /> 
                        <span style=font-size:14px>"+v1+"</span></li>";
              })
              tbl_body += tbl_row;
            })

        return tbl_body;
      }
```

The categories are getting displayed properly but when i select checkbox then following code needs to be executed

```
 function getFilterOptions(){
   var opts = [d,de];
   $checkboxes.each(function(){
     if(this.checked){
       opts.push(this.id);
   }
  return opts;
  }

  var $checkboxes = $("input:checkbox");
  $checkboxes.on("change", function(){
    var opts = getFilterOptions();
    updateProducts(opts);

  });
```

I want the ID of checkbox to be pushed to page having php code. But nothing is happening on checking checkbox. 
Note: When i view source code then `<ul id="foodtype"></ul>` code remains inact.. No `<li>` elements are displayed :(

Comment: this is not duplicate.. why down vote.. pl try to get the logic i am trying here

Answer (score 0):

You need to use something called event delegation. Listen on the click events on the container where checkboxes are. So after you add them dynamically, the click event will get bubbled to the container.

Answer (score 0):

That's because `var $checkboxes = $("input:checkbox");` is getting executed before ajax is complete and hence no elements.

Change to

```
$(document).on("change", "input:checkbox", function() {
    var opts = getFilterOptions();
    updateProducts(opts);
});
```

and it should work.

Comment: i have tried this and now ajax call is fired but no ID is getting added in Ajax req :(

Comment: @Gags, didn't get you... your ajax call has `data:''` how do you expect ID to be passed?

Comment: i got it working.. i made checkbox click in `complete` function of ajax and it is working now.. Thanks